# Parsing a SQL field in a query

Tags: sql, database, parsing

I've inherited a database of user profile information which has a column for personal interests.  Multiple interests are separated by a pipe (|).  In a SQL query, how can I split a field with this value: 2|27|33|14|15

To look like this:

```
2
27
33
14
15
```

Comment: What SQL are you using, and have you looked at the manual for string processing functions (I assume this is a VARCHAR field)? And how do you want the actual query and full output to look?

Comment: use some thing like this SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(**<<YOURSTRING>>**, '|')

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax depends on which `dbms` you are using. Assuming you are using `MSSQL` this is the general syntax

```
STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator )
```

For example

```
DECLARE @string_to_be_split NVARCHAR(400) = '2|27|33|14|15'  

SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string_to_be_split, '|')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit - Could have sworn that I saw SQL Server**

If not 2016, just about any Split/Parse Function will do.

**Option 1 - With UDF**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Interests varchar(250))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2|27|33|14|15')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Interests,'|') B
```

**Option 2 - Without a UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Interests,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       2
1   2       27
1   3       33
1   4       14
1   5       15
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: How to do in oracle?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi  Sorry, I haven't touched Oracle i almost a decade,