# Parsing a comma delimited column and transposing into rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table like this with an undetermined number of comma-delimited values in one column:

```
thingID    personID

1          123,234,345

2          456,567
```

and I want to get it into a form like this:

```
thingID    personID

1          123

1          234

1          345

2          456

2          567
```

What is my best option for doing this? 
Oh I should mention the data is in a SQL 2008 R2 database so I may not be able to use the very latest functionality.

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796532/parsing-a-sql-field-in-a-query/42796923#42796923   Here, you have a option to use a UDF of In-line approach

Comment: I think your best bet would be with while/cursor. for each ```thingId``` split ```personId``` and insert it. also, consider checking other SO questions trying to achieve just that.

Comment: @ErmirBeqiraj that's actually his worst bet.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: @JiggsJedi agree that it's the last thing to consider, couldn't think of a set-based solution at the time(that's why comment not answer). I like the "Recursive method" answer from Racil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` with a string splitting function.
To find the string splitting function that works best for you, read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way.](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

For this demonstration I've chosen to use the `SplitStrings_XML` function, simply because it's the first pure t-sql function in the article:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Now that we have a string splitting function, create and populate the sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    thingID int,
    personID varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, '123,234,345'),
(2, '456,567')
```

The query:

```
SELECT thingId, Item
FROM @T 
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(personID, ',')
```

Results:

```
thingId     Item
1           123
1           234
1           345
2           456
2           567
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/WKLFN95728)

Comment: Thanks for the really clear answer.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. Here are two methods for SQL Server 2008:

**XML-Method:** requires the string to allow for the xml-trick (no invalid XML chars)

```
SELECT a.thingID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
FROM (SELECT OtherID,  
             CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(personID, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
      FROM table1) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

**Recursive method:**

```
;WITH tmp(thingID, DataItem, Data) AS (
    SELECT thingID, LEFT(personID, CHARINDEX(',', personID + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(personID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', personID + ','), '')
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT thingID, LEFT(personID, CHARINDEX(',', personID + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(personID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', personID + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE Data > ''
)
SELECT thingID, DataItem AS personID
FROM tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; I really appreciate your taking the time. All of these methods look useful and I have been able to acheive the goal